# Executing jQuery Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around the jQuery promise function, but I think I'm missing a step.

I've created a simple example where, `onclick`, the square moves to the left. What is supposed to happen is when the square has completed it's shift, an alert fires, but I don't think my syntax is correct.  Below is my code, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var square = $('.square');

  let moveLeft = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    square.click(function() {
      square.animate({
        left: '200px'
      });
      let functionComplete = true;

      if (functionComplete == true) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });

  moveLeft.then(function() {
    alertWhenDone();
  });

  function alertWhenDone() {
    alert('The square has finished!');
  };
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Your promise will always reject.  No matter what. Maybe put resolve *inside* the click function.

Comment: What is your reasoning for wrapping click in a promise ? If you were to modify that animation to be incremental on subsequent clicks your wrapping promise would already have been resolved. This pattern doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's `animate` doesn't block execution during the animation, it queues the animation immediately and execution continues.  So, in your case `let functionComplete = true;` wouldn't happen when the animation visually completed, it would be executed immediately after the animation is queued.

What you can make use of here is the `complete` argument to `animate`, as seen in the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) `animate` can take an `options` argument that accepts a `complete` function to use as a callback.

So, the updated code snippet might look something like this:

```
let moveLeft = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    square.click(function() {
        square.animate({left: '200px'}, { complete: function() { resolve(); } });
    });
}); //end of promise
```

That code should behave as you expect - the animation will play out and only when it is complete will your Promise's `resolve` be called.

**Edit:** Of course, the use of the `Promise` here is purely artificial for learning how `Promise` works and can be used.  The `complete` callback could be used without the `Promise` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: In this case then, do the 'then' statement and the alert code exist outside the let function?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner yes, the rest of the code should be able to remain the same

Comment: Could I ask one further question in chat?

Comment: Good edit in last statement. Whole pattern doesn't make sense unless only one click on only one square will ever occur.

Comment: @charlietfl could I ask a question in chat?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner sure

Comment: @charlietfl I've created a second, more generic example where I've changed the animation to a timeout function that just alerts.  But I don;t understand where to put the resolve() function

Comment: Put it into a sandbox demo like jsfiddle.net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162822/discussion-between-theodore-steiner-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Promise to do that. You can simply add a callback function to JQuery `animate()` like so :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.square').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      left: '200px'
    },
    //This function will execute after the animation has ended
    function(){
      alert('test');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Only sensible answer. The whole promise wrapper is overkill

Answer (score -1):

It's `Promise` (capital), not `promise`.

Comment: Typing errors should be notified as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @Zenoo he explicitly said "but I don't think my syntax is correct" so I figured that might his mistake.